# Javascript - Access to values that were generated inside for loop

Tags: javascript, promise

I am willing to run a for loop inside the array `MessageContent.orderedDishes[i]` to get the values inside that array, but the problem is that `MessageContent.orderedDishes[i]` is located inside a variable called `textToSend` I can't move it outside the variable as the content of that variable will be sent to another view

```
shareWithClient(MessageContent){
    let textToSend = 
        '####################' + '\n\n' +
        'Dish : ' + MessageContent.orderedDishes[i].dishName + '\n' +
        'Category : ' +MessageContent.orderedDishes[i].categoryName+'\n' +
        'Qty  : ' + MessageContent.orderedDishes[i].qty +'\n\n'+
        '####################';

    SocialSharing.shareViaWhatsApp(textToSend).then(() => {
        // Success!
    }).catch(() => {
        // Error!
    });
}
```

Working but prints only the first element of the array, knowing that the array has 3 elements:

```
      var textToSend = '';
        for(var i=0; i<MessageContent.orderedDishes.length; i++){
       textToSend = '' +
        '####################' + '\n\n' +
        'Dish : ' + MessageContent.orderedDishes[i].dishName + '\n' +
        'Category : ' +MessageContent.orderedDishes[i].categoryName+'\n' +
        'Qty  : ' +MessageContent.orderedDishes[i].qty +'\n\n'+
        '####################';
      }
    console.log('textToSend');
```

Comment: Where's the loop?  If it's outside the shareWithClient function, just pass the ordered dish in as the parameter rather than the whole MessageContent object.

Comment: What's the problem, exactly? Where's the loop? What's `i`?

Comment: @TedHopp the problem exactly is that I want somehow to run the for loop inside `testToSend` which is obviously not possible, but in the same time I willing to find a way to get the values of the array

Comment: Did you try initializing `textToSend` to an empty string and then run a loop to append the content for each value of `i`?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a function definition? It's missing the `function` keyword at the beginning.

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly -you want to send a message, but still want to use the array values within MessageContent-, what it seems you want to do in reality is send the array of data as a message and THEN compose the string textToSend (On the view). Perhaps use JSON.stringify on MessageContent, send that as the message, and then build your string on the client.

Comment: @TedHopp, I've done an edit, I was able to print so far the first element of the array; however, it does not print all elements knowing that the array has 3 elements.

Comment: Try using `textToSend += '###...'` instead of `textToSend = '' + ...`. You want to **append** to `textToSend`, not reset it each time through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
shareWithClient(MessageContent)  {
  let text = '';
  if (MessageContent && MessageContent.orderedDishes) {
    MessageContent.orderedDishes.forEach(buildText);
  }
  shareText();

  function buildText(dish) {
    text += `####################
             Dish : ${ dish.dishName }
             Category : ${ dish.categoryName }
             Qty  : ${ dish.qty }

            ####################`;
  }

  function shareText() {
      SocialSharing.shareViaWhatsApp(text).then(() => {
        // Success!
        }).catch(() => {
        // Error!
      });
  }
```

}